# Python - OLS Regression Estimation using either statsmodels or scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I want to run a rolling for example of 3 window `OLS regression estimation` for a dataset found in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUMVFyYTEtWXlzYkk) (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2Iv8dfU4fTUMVFyYTEtWXlzYkk) as in the following format. The third column (Y) in my dataset is my true value - that's what I wanted to predict (estimate).

```
 time     X   Y
0.000543  0  10
0.000575  0  10
0.041324  1  10
0.041331  2  10
0.041336  3  10
0.04134   4  10
  ...
9.987735  55 239
9.987739  56 239
9.987744  57 239
9.987749  58 239
9.987938  59 239
```

Using a simple `OLS regression estimation`, I have tried it with the following script.

```
# /usr/bin/python -tt

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('estimated_pred.csv')

model = pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=df.Y, x=df[['X']], 
                               window_type='rolling', window=3, intercept=True)
df['Y_hat'] = model.y_predict

print(df['Y_hat'])
print (model.summary)
df.plot.scatter(x='X', y='Y', s=0.1)
```

However, using either `statsmodels` or `scikit-learn` seems to be a good choice for something beyond the a simple regression. I have tried to make the following script work but returing `IndexError: index out of bounds` with higher subset of the dataset (for example for more than 100 rows of the dataset).

```
# /usr/bin/python -tt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm


df=pd.read_csv('estimated_pred.csv')    
df=df.dropna() # to drop nans in case there are any
window = 3
#print(df.index) # to print index
df['a']=None #constant
df['b1']=None #beta1
df['b2']=None #beta2
for i in range(window,len(df)):
    temp=df.iloc[i-window:i,:]
    RollOLS=sm.OLS(temp.loc[:,'Y'],sm.add_constant(temp.loc[:,['time','X']])).fit()
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('a')]=RollOLS.params[0]
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('b1')]=RollOLS.params[1]
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('b2')]=RollOLS.params[2]

#The following line gives us predicted values in a row, given the PRIOR row's estimated parameters
df['predicted']=df['a'].shift(1)+df['b1'].shift(1)*df['time']+df['b2'].shift(1)*df['X']

print(df['predicted'])
#print(df['b2'])

#print(RollOLS.predict(sm.add_constant(predict_x)))

print(temp)
```

I want to do a prediction of `Y` (i.e. predict the current value of `Y` according to the previous value 3 rolling values of `X`. Finally, i want to include the mean squared error (`MSE`) for all the prediction (a summary of the regression analysis). For example, if we look at row 5, the value of `X` is 2 and the value of `Y` is 10. Let's say the prediction value of `y` at the current row is 6 and therefore the `mse` will be `(10-6)^2`. How can we do this using either `statsmodels` or `scikit-learn` for `pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS` was removed in `Pandas` version 0.20.0 and since I can't find any reference?